# Google Drive Application Data folder after reinstall

Tags: android, google-drive-api

1. Created an file in app folder from android app with some contents.
2. The android app entry can be seen in the manage apps tab of drive
3. After I uninstall the android app from my device, the app folder in the drive persists, with the same amount of space occupied. (so the file and its contents might still be there) 
   4.I re-install the android app on my mobile and try too read the file. But the file is not fount. (Authentication with the same gmail id on both instances)
4. Is the app folder created for every instance of installation , i mean wth cant i access the same app folder of the same account?

Comment: Hi! I have the same problema. How did you solve this?

Comment: Add  Tasks.await(driveClient.requestSync()); line in thread before restore any file from Google drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appdata folder will persist in the user's Drive until the Google Drive app is uninstalled:

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2523073?hl=en

Uninstalling the Android app does not uninstall the appdata folder. The appdata folder should be available after re-install, and from other devices as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `requestSync()` and then in its callback, query the file.

Refer to this SO ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36886520/5973371