# Android: Uploaded file in App Folder not found after app reinstall

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have implemented Google Drive backup in my app.

I upload the backup in the `App Folder`. But after I reinstall my app, it is not able to find the newly created file.

I there any workaround for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following:

1. I use `requestSync(GoogleApiClient)`
2. Then, in its callback, I query the contents of the drive using `Drive.DriveApi.query(GoogleApiClient, query)`
3. Then, in its callback, if found, retrieve the file.
4. Job done!

The snippet is given below for those interested.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    super.onConnected(connectionHint);
    Drive.DriveApi.requestSync(getGoogleApiClient()).setResultCallback(syncCallback);
}

final private ResultCallback<Status> syncCallback = new ResultCallback<Status>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
        if (!status.isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Problem while retrieving results");
            return;
        }
        query = new Query.Builder()
                .addFilter(Filters.and(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "title"),
                        Filters.eq(SearchableField.TRASHED, false)))
                .build();
        Drive.DriveApi.query(getGoogleApiClient(), query)
                .setResultCallback(metadataCallback);
    }
};

final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult> metadataCallback =
        new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Problem while retrieving results");
            return;
        }

        MetadataBuffer mdb = result.getMetadataBuffer();
        for (Metadata md : mdb) {
            Date createdDate = md.getCreatedDate();
            DriveId driveId = md.getDriveId();
        }

        readFromDrive(driveId);
    }
};
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works for me. I stuck on this issue about two days. :(

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling your application will remove data in App Folder as well. [This is from the REST API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/appdata#what_is_the_application_data_folder), but I'm guessing the same thing happens on Android and other client APIs as well.

Comment: Thanks @adjuremods. But not exactly. Refer to my accepted answer for more info.